# Docker Swarm external gateway

Tags: docker, swarm

Is it possible to configure an outbound IP from a Docker Swarm network overlay?
Example, I have several services running on Swarm. And my network interface has several IPs configured.

Is it possible that everything coming out of network X comes out through a single IP?

Or do I have to configure a gateway on the network and perform NAT with IPTables?

Thank you!